# Problema con un array en un bucle

Tags: php

Tengo un problema con un array en un bucle y es que he querido simplificar este código y me echaron una mano pero no consigo hacer que el array sea correctamente interpretado.

```
$s = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]; 
for ($i = 0; $i < count($Datos); $i++) { 
    $s1 += $Datos[$i]["Valor1"];$s2 += $Datos[$i]["Valor2"];
    $s3 += $Datos[$i]["Valor3"];$s4 += $Datos[$i]["Valor4"];
    $s5 += $Datos[$i]["Valor5"];$s6 += $Datos[$i]["Valor6"];
    $s7 += $Datos[$i]["Valor7"];$s8 += $Datos[$i]["Valor8"];
    }
```

Este es el código y lo hago correr pero la parte $s[$j] no la esta interpretando correctamente no le esta dando valor para que se quede en $s1, $s2 y así y quería saber si me podéis echar un cable he probado de múltiples formas y aparentemente debería correr sin problema.

```
$s = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];

for ($i = 0; $i < count($Datos); $i++) { 
  for ($j = 0; $j < 8; $j++) {
     $s[$j] += $Datos[$i]["Valor" . ($j+1)];
  }
}
```

Básicamente si pongo el valor $s[$j] manual si corre bien pero no me serviría debería regresar al código anterior ya que lo necesito en múltiples variables ...

**Aclaración:**

El bucle aparentemente debería funcionar pero no interpreta de forma correcta $s[$j] que debería sacar de resultado $s1, $s2 y así...

Comment: Te recomiendo editar tu pregunta y organizar el código para entender lo que estas haciendo

Comment: @Oswuell eso intento siempre pero no lo logro, cuando lo pongo tiene formato al publicar se deshace.

Comment: Mira como preguntar https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: ¿Que quieres hacer? ¿Que resultado esperas?

Comment: El bucle debería darle valor a la linea $s[$j] += $Datos[$i]["Valor" . ($j+1)];

Y debería pasara a ser $s1 += $Datos[0]["Valor" . (1+1)]; Pero por algñun motivo falla en $s[$j]  no le da el valor que necesita.

Answer (score 0):

Revisando tu codigo veo que no estas inicializando tus variables {s1,s2,...}, te recomiendo antes de ejecutar el bucle asignarlas a un valor cero `por ejemplo $s1 = 0;`. Puede que este generando resultados inesperados por meterte (basura) cuando ejecutas la suma.

Igual, edita la pregunta para tener mas información, como casos de pruebas, valores de ingreso y de salida esperado.

Así, puedo orientarte mejor.

Comment: Amigo lo comprobé todo solo falla $s[$j] que en el bucle deberia dejarlo como$s1, $s2 y así solo cambiando eso a por ejemplo$s1 ya la información la obtengo sin problema y puse las vars a 0 también y nada.

Answer (score 0):

una forma mas eficiente,clara y sencilla de hacer lo que deseas es con el uso de la funcion list() de php:

```
list($s1,$s2,$s3,$s4,$s5,$s6,$s7,$s8) = $s;
```

referencia:
http://php.net/manual/es/function.list.php

Comment: La finalidad de list es que iría dándole un valor no? he probado y tampoco lo carga así. Necesito que $s[$j] += $Datos[$i]["Valor" . ($j+1)]; al ser bucle la información de $s[$j]  pase a ser $s1, $s2 pero no hay manera no lo interpreta.

Comment: elimina el simbolo de + en todas las operaciones y listo! ya que estas concatenando a null; debes declarar esas variables antes o eliminar el simbolo de concatenacion!

Comment: Igual quitando el +1 sigue sucediendo

Comment: postea todo tu codigo y asi podremos tener una mejor vision de lo que deseas hacer!

Comment: Básicamente ese es el código obtengo los valores por while de la db se pasan  a array como puedes ver el código basto los paso por un for para darle la suma y pasarlo a $s1, $s2 para después llamarlos con echo $s1;